# using List and foreach

Tags: c#, list, foreach

Here is my code:

```
  int Temp = 200;
  List<int> PrimeBuilders = new List<int>();
  PrimeBuilders.Add(200);
  PrimeBuilders.Add(300);
  PrimeBuilders.Add(400);
  PrimeBuilders.Add(500);
  PrimeBuilders.Add(200);
  PrimeBuilders.Add(600);
  PrimeBuilders.Add(400);


  foreach(int A in PrimeBuilders)
  {

  }
```

How can I go through the list and output the index that does not contain the number assigned to `Temp`?

Comment: `foreach` doesn't really deal with indexes, you'd be better to use a for loop, or maintain your own counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need indexed you probably should go with `for` instead of `foreach`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < PrimeBuilders.Count; i++)
{
    if(PrimeBuilders[i] != Temp)
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

***Bonus:*** LINQ one-liner:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, PrimeBuilders.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).Where(x => x.x != Temp).Select(x => x.i)));
```

Comment: +1. Or you can combine 2 and `foreach(var item in PrimeBuilders.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }))...` if `foreach` is required.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
int Temp = 200;
var PrimeBuilders = new List<int> {200, 300, 400, 500, 200, 600, 400};

for (int i = 0; i < PrimeBuilders.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Current index: " + i);

    if (PrimeBuilders[i] != Temp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match found at index: " + i);
    }
}
```

Firstly, you can initialize your list with 1 line.
Secondly, if you need an index, then foreach will not give you that. You need a for loop, as shown above.

Comment: hi sir, what if i need to output the index that has the value Temp on it. How will i be able to show it? Thank you

Comment: Just change   if (PrimeBuilders[i] != Temp)   to   if (PrimeBuilders[i] == Temp).

Comment: Sir is it possible to output the index number of the chosen values. Sorry for the noob questions sir

Comment: It should already do that. The line Console.WriteLine(i); outputs any index which matches the condition in the 'if' statement.

Comment: i mean sir for example the 0,1,2,3 and so on